# load attr("href") plus specific content div

Tags: html, load, href, attr

I'm loading a link into a popup like this: `popup.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));`
This is working, but more specifically I only want the content within the `.include` div of the loaded `href`. How would I update the code above to call the content within `.include` in said `href`?

Thankyou